# what is "HTTP_ALEXATOOLBAR_ALX_NS_PH"

Tags: php, alexa-internet

I was just going through the output of phpinfo() of a php file of my server. I came across a php variable called

```
_SERVER["HTTP_ALEXATOOLBAR_ALX_NS_PH"]
```

What is this variable for? What does this have to do with the alexa toolbar??

thanks

Comment: um ... there are no HTTP-variables in php.ini. Maybe you should correct your question or else noone will be able to make sense of it.

Comment: If you mean you see this when you do `var_dump($_SERVER)`, then it simply means that it's an HTTP header sent by the Alexa toolbar (as it seems). What this has to do with php.ini I don't know either.

Comment: sorry... my bad. not php.ini.. i meant when i do phpinfo() in a php file

Answer (score -1):

This header comes from the browser extension Alexa Toolbar. This extension sniffs your traffic.

Comment: What does that have to do with phpinfo that is shown by the server?